# How do I redirect htaccess pages with no extension?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use htaccess to redirect certain pages on my site to different pages. However, my site was built using Convergence CMS and the URLs have no extension. I have tried using the following redirect command but for some reason this is not working on pages without an extension:

```
Redirect 301 /page-name http://www.domain.com/new-page
```

Is my syntax wrong or do I need to include other commands?

Comment: Perhaps the space in "new page" is causing problems.

Comment: Sorry, there was not actually a space there, just a typo when I asked the question. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As @showdev mentioned, the space causes an internal server error. Does the following solve it?

```
Redirect 301 /page-name http://www.domain.com/new%20page
```

Comment: No, I didn't actually have a space in my entry. Any other ideas?